# Как решейпить массив

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Допустим, я прочитал из csv файла строку, репрезентирующую изображение 41x41 (RGBA)

Например, `image_csv = "255,255,255,0,..."`

Я помещаю в `image_array` эту строку за**split**ченную через запятую.

`image_array = image_csv.split(',')`

В итоге получается массив `[255, 255, 255, 0,...]`. В этом списке элементов 6724 = 41 * 41 * 4 (потому что 4 канала на каждый пиксель)

Теперь я хочу просмотреть это изображение используя `matplotlib`. Естественно, такой код не даст мне нужного результата

```
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(image_array)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

В связи с этим у меня вопрос. Как мне отобразить это изображение? Нужно ли через `numpy` зарешейпить `image_array` в трёхмерную матрицу `(41, 41, 4)`? Если да, то как я могу это сделать?

Спасибо

Comment: Ещё в int надо всё перевести, у вас же строки, а не числа

Comment: @CrazyElf, ой... точно. спасибо. совсем забыл

Answer (score 0):

Должно сработать, и именно через `reshape` (в `Numpy` все операции обычно называются понятным и логичным образом):

```
image_array = np.array(map(int, image_csv.split(','))).reshape((41,41,4))
```

Проверил в Google Colab на искусственных данных - вроде рисует что-то, как и задумано:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

n = 41
img = np.array([0, 255, 0, 200] * n * n).reshape((n, n, 4))
cv2_imshow(img)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]